# onclick pop to work once every page reloads

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <script language="javascript"><!--

 function PopUp() {

var TheURL = "http://www.widgetsu.com/";
var PopWidth = "1000";
var PopHeight = "1000";
var PosTop = "";
var PosLeft = "";

var SettingS = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=" + PopWidth + ",height=" + PopHeight + ",top=" + PosTop + ",left=" + PosLeft;
var PopUp = open(TheURL,"box",SettingS);
 }

 window.onclick=PopUp;

 // -->
 </script>
```

The onclick pop up works when ever i click, how can i make it to work only once wen ever a page reloads

Comment: window.onload=PopUp; replace onclick with onload

Answer (score 1):

You could have some sort of global variable to keep track of if it's been clicked or not.

For example:

```
<script language="javascript"><!--

var clicked = false;

function PopUp() {
    if (!clicked) {
        // Your previous function code here

        clicked = true;
    }
}

window.onclick=PopUp;

// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `onload="PopUp()"` in the body tag.